# HTML Add images dynamically to iframe (like a text editor)

Tags: html, iframe

can anybody tell me hw to add images in an iframe at runtime. I am making a text editor using iframe and i want the facility for the user to add images to it by clicking a button.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. An `iframe` is an HTML object. What do you mean by "runtime" and that you are making a text editor using the `iframe`?

Comment: sorry if i wasnt clear...the thing is im making a text editor and for that purpose im using the iframe in design mode. this way the user can enter text on the webpage just like writting in a notepad. it works fine...but nw i want to add images to iframe. By runtime i meant that the user opens the webpage clicks on the image button, browses the image and then that image shud be displayed in the iframe along with the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to upload your image to your site so you need to create a backend piece of code that manages that, you can send your image to the site via an Ajax call, and have the server respond with the same image.

Try looking here http://css-tricks.com/6522-ajax-image-uploading/

After that you should just display it in your iframe.

Comment: Thanks...lets say i have the image file xyz.jpg...i dont think this code will display the image cauze in the code i think i wud need to give the image file path! so where wud it be? cheers

Comment: I think I understood what you are trying to accomplish here. Changing my answer accordingly

Comment: No problem, please consider voting this answer as solution to your problem if it helped. It's the green check sign under the voting widget, I'm telling you this only because I see you are new to the site :)